# Can't figure out why my div rotation is tearing out my layout

Tags: html, jquery, css

I want to make an horizontal scroll container within my webpage, i tried using css `transform` to rotate `div` container `-90deg` and also did same for children element of div with rotate `90deg` to make dem look normal... but its tearing out my entire layout and adding extra width to the overall container `div`

here is the html and css code below

```
 <section class="section-three">
        <h1>Works</h1>
        <div class="image-slider-wrap">
          <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">6</a></li>
        </div>
      </section>
```

Css

```
.section-three {
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
  background: yellow;
 
  @media screen and (min-width: 44em) {
    padding: 50px 10px 300px 250px;
  }
}


.image-slider-wrap {
  width: 400px;
  height: auto;
  background: red;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  position: relative;
  top: -900px;
  transform-origin: left;

  li {
    width: 200px;
    height: 400px;
    background: blue;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
}
```

My overall aim is to achieve a horizontal scroll when i scroll up and down.  Please anyone with a better alternative or a solution to help with my current trick should help out...Thanks alot in advance

Comment: Hi, horizontal scrolling does not occur because of rotated content. You will actually have to place the content outside the viewport. (or make the content not fit the width of the screen). So forget about rotating, you dont need it. To make the page scroll to the right instead of down, you would need some javascript.. plenty of those around. example: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/horz-scroll-with-mouse-wheel/

Comment: i have achieved my goal without js and its working fine....Thanks